# User deactivation in Django

Tags: django, slug, django-users

I am trying to allow users to deactivate their accounts on my django website. Here is what I have tried:

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@login_required
def deactivate_user(request, username):
    context = {}
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        context['msg'] = 'Profile successfully disabled.'
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        context['msg'] = 'User does not exist.'
    except Exception as e:
        context['msg'] = e.message

    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

urls.py

```
path('deactivate-user/<slug:username>', deactivate_user, name='deactivate_user'),
```

base.html

```
<form action="{% url 'users:deactivate_user' slug=username.slug %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="active">Yes, Deactivate</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

I am getting a NoReverseMatch error `Reverse for 'deactivate_user' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/deactivate\\-user/(?P<username>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']` Have tried a few different parameters in the template but can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying

```html
<form action="{% url 'users:deactivate_user' slug=username.slug %}" method="post">
```

`slug` isn't a keyword in your pattern, its a type, similar to `<int:pk>`, it should be `username=username.slug`

Comment: Thank you, but I am still receiving the error. Now it says `Reverse for 'deactivate_user' with keyword arguments '{'username': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/deactivate\\-user/(?P<username>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']`

Comment: @sgt_pepper85 try adding a backslash in `urls.py` + try changing the type to `str` by alternating `<slug:username>` to `<str:username>` and in template `action = {% username = user.username %}` take into consideration the way how are you iterating over users.